# Not able to access sharepoint list using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, rest, ajax

This is my code

```
function getListItem(url, listname, id, complete, failure) {
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('"+ listname +"')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            complete(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
};
```

The `url` is coming correctly, also on checkng the full `url` parameter in `ajax` call, it is returning data when i open that in new tab

But since this `ajax` call is made inside a sharepoint app that is in a different domain, its throwing an error - `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

What change should i make in my site to make that list available for cross domain call.

Info:
the site url is `http://www.vignesh.cloudappsportal.com/`
The app url is `xxxx.apps.cloudappsportal.net/CloudAppsTrial/Pages/Default.aspx`

Answer (score 3):

Cross domain calls are blocked by modern web browsers due to security concerns.  To get round this you can use the [SP.RequestExecutor.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx) script to relay messages to SharePoint from within the same domain.

Example

```
function getListItem(hostUrl,appWebUrl, listTitle,itemId,success,error) 
{
    var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")?@target='" + hostUrl + "'";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
           url: url,
           method: "GET",
           headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
           success: function (data) {
                var results = eval(JSON.parse(data.body));
                success(results);
           },
           error: error
       });
}
```

Usage

```
var appWebUrl,hostUrl;
var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
     var param = params[i].split("=");
     switch (param[0]) {
        case"SPAppWebUrl":
          appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
            break;
        case"SPHostUrl":
          hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
           break;
     }
}

$.getScript(hostUrl + "/_Layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function (data) {

   getListItem(hostUrl,appWebUrl, 'Tasks',1,function(data){
       console.log(data); 
   },
   function(error){
      //error handling goes here.. 
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typical **Same-Origin-Policy** issue that may be solved configuring CORS on the *remote* server, and may be worked around proxying the communication between your server and the remote server: put *some piece of software* in your server that performs the real requests to the remote server. This way, all the calls from your browser will be to the local server, who performs the target call.
Unfortunately these are not very straigthforward solutions.
In the first case you need to modify server configuration, which is not always possible. 
In the second case you could have some problems with authentication forwarding.
Please search for CORS or Same-Origin-Policy as this is a quite common issue.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

A sharepoint app essentially exists in a domain. So you need to either use `SP.RequestExecutor.js` or use `SP.AppContextSite`

This is the structure of the URL if using `SP.AppContextSite`

```
var url = appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Title,ID&@target='" + hostUrl + "'";
```

This is the general structure of the call if Uisng `SP.RequestExecutor.js`

```
var scriptbase = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {

            var url =  appwebUrl +
                      "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Title,ID&@target='" + hostUrl + "'";


            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appwebUrl);
            executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url:     url,
                method:  "POST",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
                success: function () {alert('success')},
                error:   function(){alert("error");
            }
```

You need to get `hostUrl` and `webUrl` from the querystring using string operations.

Source :  [MSDN Rest Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem)